# Why startOfMonth results in different timezone that endOfMonth

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am trying to get proper start and end of month values using `date-fns`. My browser timezone is `UTC+2` (as `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` results in `-120`).

Example code:

```
console.log('start of month: ', dateFns.startOfMonth(new Date()));
console.log('end of month: ', dateFns.endOfMonth(new Date()));
```

result:

```
start of month:  Thu Oct 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (czas środkowoeuropejski letni)
end of month:  Sat Oct 31 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)
```

Why `startOfMonth` results in timezone `GMT+0200` while `endOfMonth` results in `GMT+1`? Is it possible to get proper values of timezones (GMT+0200) for both cases?

Comment: Probably because October is the month we change time for winter saving time. GMT timezone doesn't change its time, but you do, creating a 1 hour shift relative to it.

Comment: Just blindguessing, could it be that for your location you have daylight saving time change this month?

Comment: Seems that your are right, guys :+1: